# AWS ACM で ELB を通さずにSSL証明書を利用することはできますか？

Tags: aws, ssl

２年前にはAWS以外のクラウドを利用していてSSL証明書も別のサイトで取得したんですが
その証明書がもうすぐ切れそうになっていて
現在サーバーは EC2 でドメインは Route53 で管理してるため
証明書も AWS ACM で管理した方がいいかなと思って調べていたんですが
ELB というのを挟んで利用するという記事しか出てきません

サーバーの apache とか nginx に証明書をおいて再起動するだけみたいな証明書を
AWS ACM で取得することはできないんでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

まず、ACMはAWS Certificate Managerの略ですから、AWS ACMと表記するのは誤りです。

[サービスと AWS Certificate Manager の統合](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html)に

> ACM 証明書またはプライベート ACM PCA 証明書を AWS ベースのウェブサイトとアプリケーションに直接インストールすることはできません。次のサービスの 1 つを使用する必要があります。

が全てかと思います。